# slug url and after more pages

Tags: django, slug

I do not understand how you could generate urls after the slug field, enter stop another page as django ago to save the slug field value or a value that should go to views.py

I have in models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import permalink

class Blog(models.Model):
    title =     models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug =      models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body =      models.TextField()
    posted =    models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    category =  models.ForeignKey('blog.Category')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('view_blog_post', None, {'slug': self.slug})
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
        return render_to_response('index.html', {'categories':Category.objects.all(), 'posts': Blog.objects.all()[:5]})

def view_post(request, slug):
        return render_to_response('view_post.html', {'post':get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=slug)})

def view_details(request, slug):
            return render_to_response('view_details.html', {'post':get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=slug)})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', 'blog.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^blog/view/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)', 'blog.views.view_post', name='view_blog_post'),
    url(r'^blog/view/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)'/details, 'blog.views.view_details', name='view_blog_details'),
)
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block titulo %} My blog {% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
<h2>posts</h2>
    {% if posts %}
        <ul>
        {% for post in posts %}
        <li><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{post.title}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No hay post's</p>
    {% endif%}
{% endblock %}
```

view_post.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head_title %} {{post.title}} {% endblock %}
{% block title %} {{post.title}} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {{post.body}}
{% endblock %}
```

I can not make a url like

localhost: 8000/field-slug/details

does not work this url somebody could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change slug pattern and add $ to the end of urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'blog.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^blog/view/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'blog.views.view_post', name='view_blog_post'),
    url(r'^blog/view/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/details/$', 'blog.views.view_details', name='view_blog_details'),
)
```